# Which image to use for Jenkins from DockerHub? There are multiple types of images are listed?

Tags: docker, jenkins

jenkins
jenkins/jenkins
jenkinsci/jenkins

What is the difference between jenkins/jenkins and jenkinsci/jenkins docker images?

Answer (score 1):

If you check https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkinsci/jenkins/, it has the deprecation notice which states:

DEPRECATED

This image has been deprecated in favor of the [jenkins/jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/) image provided and maintained by Jenkins Community as part of project's release process.

Similar notice is present on their Github repo: https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker

So following is the Jenkins official link: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/